# Obtener el valor de un desplegable (select) con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo este código HTML para crear un combobox a partir de un enumerado

**Enumerado**

```
public enum tipoFormasPago
{
    [Display(Name = "Efectivo")]
    E,
    [Display(Name = "Tarjeta")]
    T,
    [Display(Name = "Paypal")]
    P
}
```

**Código HTML**

```
<td>Forma de pago</td>
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList(
        "formaDePago",
        EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(testweb.Classes.EnumUtils.tipoFormasPago)),
        "Selecciona",
        new { @class = "formaDePago form-control" }
    )
    <span class="error">Forma de pago obligatoria</span>
</td>
```

Si miro el HTML con firebug veo lo siguiente:

```
<select class="formaDePago form-control" id="formaDePago" name="formaDePago">
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="0">Efectivo</option>
    <option value="1">Tarjeta</option>
    <option value="2">Paypal</option>
</select>
```

Y desde el javascript quiero recoger el valor del combobox, para ello he probado de estas maneras pero siempre recibo `"0"`:

```
var var1 = $('#formaDePago').find('option:selected').val();
var var2 = $('select[name=formaDePago]').val();
```

Además me gustaría que los valores se completaran con el enumerado que tengo creado.

Gracias.

Answer (score 6):

Para obtener el valor solo necesitas el `.val` de todos modos te dejo el codigo para sacar el `option` y el `valor`

**Espero esto te sirva**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formaDePago").click(function(){
        var select = $("#formaDePago option:selected").text();
        var valor= $("#formaDePago").val();
        $("#selector").val(select)
       $("#valor").val(valor)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="formaDePago form-control" id="formaDePago" name="formaDePago">
 <option value="">Selecciona</option>

 <option value="E">Efectivo</option>

 <option value="T">Tarjeta</option>

 <option value="P">Paypal</option>

</select>
<input id="selector"></input>
<input id="valor"></input>
```

Comment: Gracias ivan ya recojo bien el valor con jquery , ahora solo me falta saber porque el desplegable me pone los valores 0 , 1 , 2 y no me pone "E" , "T"  o "P" como tengo definido en el enumerado.

Comment: Edite la respuesta.

Comment: Te suguiero que lo hagas via HTML

Comment: Al tener un enumerado definido en la clase creo que es más elegante hacerlo de esta forma , ya que si añado otro item he de revisar todos los sitios donde tengo este desplegable.

Comment: por que no lo llenas via BD?

Comment: creo que es más cómodo por enumerado , si se puede claro. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el valor seleccionado del `select` solo necesitas:

```
$('#formaDePago').val();
```

Mira eeste ejemplo:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var var2 = $('#formaDePago').val();
  alert("valor: " + var2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="formaDePago form-control" id="formaDePago" name="formaDePago">
 <option value="">Selecciona</option>
 <option value="0">Efectivo</option>
 <option value="1">Tarjeta</option>
 <option value="2">Paypal</option>
</select>
<button>Mostrar valor</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

no se si te sea de ayuda para lo que quieres hacer pero MVC5 (5.2) rectifico tiene un helper nuevo para los enumerables. y tu ejemplo funciona, no te muesta E, T y P porque lo tienes definido de manera inversa.

Prueba de esta forma
en el modelo creas tu enum

```
public enum Tipo
{
     [Display(Name = "Efectivo")]
     E,
     [Display(Name = "Tarjeta")]
     T,
     [Display(Name = "Paypal")]
     P
}

public class PruebaViewModel
{

    public Tipo? Tipo { get; set; }


}
```

y en tu vista

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Tipo, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

y en tu controlador preguntas

```
if (prueba.Tipo == Tipo.E)
```

espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: He probado este código en mvc5 (uso framework 4.5) y me devuelte esto
<option value="">Selecciona</option>
<option value="0">E</option>
<option value="1">T</option>
<option value="2">P</option>

Comment: si despues fue que entendi lo que querias recoger. lo que definas en Dispaly name es lo que se muestra y lo otro es el cont, pero a la hora de renderizar el form los valores te los da con 0,1 etc pues enum es un array, por lo que el interpreta que el valor en la posición 0 sería "Efectivo". después fue que entendí que querías una E en vez de 0.